# Validation message is not shown while validating a form in struts 2 framwork

Tags: struts2

I have a form with struts tag, i wanted to perform validation on this form, so i created coressponding actionname-validation.xml file with actionname-properties file, the problem is that the error message done in xml file is not shown. I have checked the struts.xml file, it's fine. But i don't know what is wrong?? Can anyone help me??

Comment: Follow this [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/client-validation.html) it would help you to solve

Comment: Describe a bit more your problem please. What theme are you using? Default theme? Is Struts2 executing the validation even it doesn't shows the messages? Is it showing a error with *there isn't action mapped with result input*?

Comment: Try to put `<s:fielderror />` tag to your page. Do you see messages after that?

Comment: I have placed <s:fielderror/> in my form too, but it won't get displayed also, i have tried placing <s:fielderror fieldName="name"> in my form, this also doesn't displays the validation message.

Comment: @Binay Could you show us some code snippets. It is very difficult to guess w/o seeing actual code.

Comment: @Pigueiras Yes i have mapped the action with result name "input" to the same page of form

Comment: @Binay Edit your question to put more info. Don't use the comments :-)

Comment: Guys i don't know what was wrong...but i tried non-field validation, and it worked..anyways, thanks for ur help..:)